# Transfer an argument from javascript to html and again to javascript script in google scripts html context

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am starting from javascript in google scripts (apps scripts) bounded to a sheet.
I succesfully open html in a sidebar.
Also I add an argument I want to use later, to htmlTemplate object.

```
//OPEN THE FORM IN SIDEBAR with argument passed to formTemplate
function showFormInSidebar(argument ='I want pass this') { 
  let htmlName = 'Index'
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(htmlName)
  htmlTemplate.argument = argument;
  var html = htmlTemplate.evaluate();  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Next, I use Index.html.
I can read there my argument with some google scripts stuff, test1 is ok.

Then I check I can see an action from my secondary javascript function - test2. I can run it with click (or on 'load' event). This works fine.

And the main question is how to obtain my argument value inside a secondary JS?
Direct arg pass not working. Argument inside secondaryJS is anyway only an event object. There is a huge amount of data there, but my initial argument I cannot find.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('click', secondaryJS); 
      function secondaryJS(event){                 
        console.log('look event', event);
        document.getElementById("mytest2").innerHTML = 'This is replacing ok'
    // Wish to make some operations here, like
   let processedResult = argument + 'some more'
        document.getElementById("mytest3").innerHTML = '???? want pass result from here, using initial argument inside of this function'
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>test1, reading argument from htmlTemplate.argument, ok:</p>
    <p><?!= argument ?></p>

    <p>test2:</p>    
    <p id = "mytest2">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with string value after page load, ok</p>

    <p>test3:</p>
    <p id = "mytest3">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with result which is initial argument processed in an event listener function, NOTok</p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('click', secondaryJS); 
      function secondaryJS(event){                 
        console.log('look event', event);
        let initialParam = '<?!= argument ?>';
        let result = ''; //I initialize this variable here, but you can override this with your actual processing
        /*
            Do some processing with initialParam
            I will assume that you are storing the result
            of this processing into a variable called result
        */
        document.getElementById("mytest2").innerHTML = 'This is replacing ok'
        document.getElementById("mytest3").innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>test1, reading argument from htmlTemplate.argument, ok:</p>
    <p><?!= argument ?></p>

    <p>test2:</p>    
    <p id = "mytest2">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with string value after page load, ok</p>

    <p>test3:</p>
    <p id = "mytest3">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with argument passed from event listener function, NOTok</p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

You just put your argument as a value, just like you did in your first test.

Comment: Thanks, it is close, but not exactly. Can I somehow extract this argument inside a secondaryJS function? I need a lot of operation with it there, and html output has to be the result of these operations

Comment: @Dmytrq sure. I have edited my answer, basically I get this initial argument into a variable, you can implement the parsing as you like, store your result into a variable called `result` and then assign it as the HTML value. If my answer helped you solve this issue, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Unbelievable, but it works :) I expected ```initialParam``` will be a string ```'<?!= argument ?>'```, not an ```argument``` itself.
But it works exactly as I needed :)
Greatly appreciate.

Comment: @Dmytrq to explain: your server-side's template engine looks at your template and searches for values to be evaluated and filled. When reaching your param, it will evaluate it and write it into your structure and, by the time your Javascript evaluates it, it's already containing the actual stuff that you need. Since it's a text, we handle it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<p><?!= argument ?></p>

document.getElementById("mytest3").innerHTML = '???? want pass initial argument here'
```

To this:

```
<p id = "mytest1"><?!= argument ?></p>

document.getElementById("mytest3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mytest1").innerHTML;
```

Comment: This is really interesting hack, and it works. I didn't catch it first.
Probably I can use it somewhere.
But main wish is an ability to use initial argument INSIDE a secondaryJS. Probably I will need a lot of operations there. So the InnerHTML replacing has to be the result of secondaryJS calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

GAS:

```
function showFormInSidebar(b ='I want pass this') { 
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah2');//My file is named "ah2.html"
  t.a = b;
  var html = t.evaluate();  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>test1, reading argument from htmlTemplate.argument, ok:</p>
    <p><?= a ?></p>

    <p>test2:</p>    
    <p id = "mytest2">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with string value after page load, ok</p>

    <p>test3:</p>
    <p id = "mytest3">Must be replaced from secondaryJS with argument passed from event listener function, NOTok</p>    

    <script>
      var v = <?= a ?>;//declare a global so it persists into client side
      console.log('v=%s',v);
      window.addEventListener('click', secondaryJS); 
      function secondaryJS(event){                 
        console.log('look event', event);
        document.getElementById("mytest2").innerHTML = v
        document.getElementById("mytest3").innerHTML = v
      }
      console.log("script");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sidebar:

[image]

Comment: This will pass argument directly from initial js to html. I already can do this in test1.
But the question is how to pass this argument to secondary scripts I will use from event listener.

Comment: Finally got it.  Sorry it took so long.